# Insert substring content into new column at data insertion

Tags: mysql

I have table table with three columns as follows

```
CREATE TABLE `auto_bulk` (
  `bulk_id` int(5) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `heading` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `content` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`bulk_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I need to add some bulk records directly to mysql database.

```
INSERT INTO auto_bulk(heading,content)VALUES('xxx','xxx');
```

But my problem is I am giving only the content,heading should be the first 5 letters of content.Like,

```
INSERT INTO auto_bulk(heading,content)VALUES('Hello','Helloworld123');
```

I know how to do with php with **substr** but i would like to know is there any way to do it directly in mysql
I have tried this but no luck

```
INSERT INTO auto_bulk(heading,content)VALUES(SUBSTRING(content,1,5),'Helloworld123');
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
INSERT INTO auto_bulk(content,heading)
SELECT @var := 'Helloworld123', SUBSTRING(@var,1,5);
```

Comment: FYI, I had to correct my first try.  Try the revised answer.  I double checked and it works.  Basically using the @ variable allows you to refer to it again in the SUBSTRING.  I switched the order of the field names in the insert.

Comment: Hooray This is great...:) Thanks Buddy you saved my time.Now i learned another thing in mysql.he he thanks. I will accept your answer whenever i can.

Answer (score 1):

Create a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger like this:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER auto_bulk_trigger1
    BEFORE INSERT
    ON auto_bulk
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET NEW.heading = LEFT(NEW.content, 5);
END
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Then insert just content:

```
INSERT INTO auto_bulk(content) VALUES('Helloworld123');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a variable before you make your query like...

```
$first_five = substr($text, 0, 5);
```

Then use

```
INSERT INTO auto_bulk(heading,content)VALUES($first_five,$text);
```

or a more direct method assuming you pre-assign the $text variable:

```
INSERT INTO auto_bulk(heading,content)VALUES(substr($text, 0, 5) , $text);
```

Comment: this is not "directly in mysql" as asked

Comment: @Devon Thanks friend a already knew this i just wanted to do it with only mysql

Comment: @vinu: Oh sorry I mis-read the question; sometimes I just read too fast for my own good and make assumptions.